# Can the .coef_ property of a fitted xgboost model give an indication of which are the most important features?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

This question is specific for a XGBClassifier API using a "gblinear" booster.
As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65236416/is-there-a-formal-explanation-of-how-coefficients-of-xgboost-gblinear-model-fo), the .coef_ property returns, as the xgboost doc says [here](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBRegressor.coef_) an array of type [n_classes, n_features].

Using this array how can I order the features by importance?

Comment: May I ask why this question was closed. I was not given feedback. I do not believe this question requires more details or clarity. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, although the base learner is a linear model, the magnitude of the coefficients will not indicate how important they are. Even more so when the coefficients are not scaled. You can look at it as the magnitude of the coefficients are dependent of the scale / variation of your predictors, but does not tell you how useful it will be in predicting the correct value. You can check [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/230388/how-does-linear-base-learner-works-in-boosting-and-how-does-it-works-in-the-xgb) on more details of how the base learner works.

If you are already using scikit-learn and xgboost underneath it, there is a [help page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/ensemble/plot_gradient_boosting_regression.html#plot-feature-importance) on plotting the importance of the variables, and you can work with that.

Comment: I believe second link does not use xgboost underneath. It is using gradient boosting but not xgboost. In xgboost the method .feature_importances_ : https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBRegressor.feature_importances_ is not defined for linear learners. If I would use the scikit learn and more specifically the gradient based learning then plot_importances might be a good option. But I am not using this. Thanks anyway for the answer.